# Parsing data with grok filter on logstash

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

I'm having problems using grok filter on logstash.
I have this log:

> 83.149.9.216 - - [04/Jan/2015:05:13:42 +0000]

And I want to parse the IP and the date.
I have the code below but I'm getting no matches.

```
^%{IPV4:req_id} - - \[(?<date>%{DAY}/%{MONTH}/%{YEAR}:%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND} +0000)]
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `%{DAY}` (=day of the *week* name) to `%{MONTHDAY}` (to match the *numbers*) and escape the `+` to match it as a literal `+` char:

```
^%{IPV4:req_id} - - \[(?<date>%{MONTHDAY}/%{MONTH}/%{YEAR}:%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND} \+0000)]
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^                                              ^
```

As suggested by [Calvin Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3779344/calvin-taylor), you may further enhance the pattern to match any ISO8601 time zone with `%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}` instead of `\+0000`:

```
^%{IPV4:req_id} - - \[(?<date>%{MONTHDAY}/%{MONTH}/%{YEAR}:%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE})]
                                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [Grok patterns](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns):

```
MONTHDAY (?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12][0-9])|(?:3[01])|[1-9])
DAY (?:Mon(?:day)?|Tue(?:sday)?|Wed(?:nesday)?|Thu(?:rsday)?|Fri(?:day)?|Sat(?:urday)?|Sun(?:day)?)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question. I have this: 
`^%{IPV4:req_id} - - \[(?<date>%{MONTHDAY}/%{MONTH}/%{YEAR}:%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE})] "(?<request>%{WORD}) (?<path>%{UNIXPATH}) (?<something>[^"]*)" %{NUMBER:number} %{NUMBER:number1} "(?<link>[^"]*)" "(?<browser>[^/]*)/(?<browser_version>[^\s]*) \((?<OS>[^;]*); (?<os_version>[^)]*)\) (?<remain>.*)$`

it is working well in grok debugger but when I run in logstash I have a timeout error. Do you know why?

Comment: @SLFlor It makes no sense: the pattern seems to be written well (linear pattern matching is ensured). Is there any specific error shown? Just timeout?

Comment: Just "Timeout executing grok". But if I wait a little bit it works. Strange thing

Comment: @SLFlor I checked the Grok patterns and the `%{NUMBER}` is a bit "expensive". It may be the culprit here. Try replacing `%{NUMBER:number}` with `(?<number>[+-]?\d*\.?\d+)`. Or even `(?<number>[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`. Same with `number1`. Or `(?<number>[+-]?(?>\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+))` - just make sure you match the right number format.